# Why is the result of (a+b+c')(a'b'+c) not 1?

Tags: boolean-logic

So I got his problem as homework in my course, when I solved it the result I came up with was 1, but everywhere I check the solution stops at line 4 is if it is the final solution, but I can't spot the error in my logic for some reason!

```
Line1: (a+b+c')(a'b'+c)
Line2: =aa'b'+ba'b'+c'a'b'+ac+bc+c'c
Line3: =0+0+c'a'b'+ac+bc+0
Line4: =c'a'b'+ac+bc
Line5: =c'a'b'+c(a+b)
Line6: =c'+c(a'b'+(a+b))
Line7: =1*(a'b'+(a+b))
Line8: =1
```

Comment: If you expand Line6: =c'+c(a'b'+(a+b)) = c'+ca'b'+c(a+b), is it the same you had in line 5?

Comment: actually Line6 is supposed to be this way:

Line6: =(c'+c)(a'b'+(a+b))

But OOOOOOh now I see where is my brain's logic is broken! I am taking an element with its complement  as common factors (as if they are two identical elements)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about boolean algebra / mathematics instead of directly about programming / coding / programming tools / software algorithms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do a very little bit better if XOR (`^`) is a primitive operation in your system:

```
Line1:   (a+b+c')(a'b'+c)
Line2: = aa'b'+ba'b'+c'a'b'+ac+bc+c'c
Line3: = 0+0+c'a'b'+ac+bc+0
Line4: = c'a'b'+ac+bc
Line5: = c'a'b'+c(a+b)
Line6: = c'a'b'+c(a'b')'
Line7: = c^(a'b')
```

Your error is the following:

```
Line5: = c'a'b'+c(a+b)
Line6: = c'+c(a'b'+(a+b))
```

Clearly, lines 5 and 6 do not show equivalent expressions because `c=0` satisfies the second regardless of `a` and `b` whereas `c=0, a=1` does not satisfy the first.